# Mono for Android won't build - Can't find Novell.MonoDroid.CSharp.targets

Tags: c#, android, windows-7, monodevelop, xamarin.android

I followed all of the instructions, and install completed successfully. In MonoDevelop, I go to:
`New Solution -> C# -> Mono for Android -> Mono for Android Application`, just as it says. When I go to build it, MonoDevelop throws an error, saying:

`C:\Users\[NAME]\Documents\Android\HelloAndroid1\HelloAndroid1\HelloAndroid1.csproj: Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-2.10.8\lib\mono\xbuild\Novell\Novell.MonoDroid.CSharp.targets: Project file could not be imported, it was being imported by C:\Users\[NAME]\Documents\Android\HelloAndroid1\HelloAndroid1\HelloAndroid1.csproj: Imported project: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-2.10.8\lib\mono\xbuild\Novell\Novell.MonoDroid.CSharp.targets" does not exist. (HelloAndroid1)`

In addition, under References, "Mono.Android" has an error, and says,
`Assembly not available for Android 2.2 (Froyo) (in Mono 2.10.8 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-2.10.8))`.

How do I fix this? Uninstalling and reinstalling doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your Active Runtime is set to Microsoft.Net.  There should be a combobox on the toolbar for it, or an option in the Project menu.

Comment: Can you be more specific ? I can't find "Active Runtime" in the project settings :(

Comment: Lescai: It should be on the toolbar or Project menu (not project settings).  The combobox should say either "Debug" or "Release" and if you click it you can pick "Defualt Runtime", "Microsoft .NET", or "Mono."

Comment: I am actually doing the other way. I was using .NET runtime and now I tried the Mono. I still would like to know why is does not work and why is it there? For what kind of situations? Thanks.

Comment: How do I do this on Mac?